# Android 2.3 ImageView button not working

Tags: android, google-play

I've created an ImageView button nested in a LinearLayout. The functionality of the button redirects to the Google Play market. on all devices except 2.3 it works perfectly. For 2.3 it does show Google play unless it has previously been opened.

```
View moreView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.moreView);

moreView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent LaunchIntent = mContext.getPackageManager()
                             .getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        mContext.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    }
});
```

The xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/appMain_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/app_white_bg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.app.ui.views.TextViewWithFont
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <com.app.ui.views.TextViewWithFont
            android:id="@+id/moreView"
            style="@style/SmallButtonStyleApp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/common_more"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I think this is a problem with comsumption of clicks which behaves differently between versions. But I have been unable to pinpoint the problem. It is not a an NPE from the view inflation. The TextViewWithFont class is a simple class with the ability to set a custom font.

Comment: provide related codes

Comment: And now please also your inflated xml.

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: it doesn't open google play in 2.3. only if google play is already open does it bring the activity to the front.